# How to overcome "Out of stack space error" in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear the data from cell A5 to A10 if the count in A3 is not equal to 6. I have written an "If statement" but it gives me out of stack error. How do I overcome this error

I have tried an "if statement" but it gives me error.

```
Dim Count As Integer
Dim BundleDup As Integer
Dim duplicateall As Integer
Dim SAPError As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Count = Range("A3").Value
    BundleDup = Range("B3").Value
    duplicateall = Range("C3").Value
    SAPError = Range("D3").Value

    If Target.Address = "$A$10" And Count = 6 And BundleDup = 0 And duplicateall = 0 And SAPError = 0 Then

        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
        Application.Wait waitTime
        Call MoveData
    End If

    If Count <> 6 Then
        Call ClearData
    End If

End Sub
```

The code works fine if I am not using this

```
 If Count <> 6 Then
        Call ClearData
    End If
```

But once I use this and enter value in A5 to A10, it will clear the data but it will get stuck and give me the error.

The ClearData module includes the following code:

```
Sub ClearData()
'
' ClearData Macro
'

'
    Range("A5:A10").Select
    Range("A10").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A5").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Disable events first using `application.enableevents = false` then set it back to true after the code that clears the cells.

Comment: I don't ever recommend disabling events.  There are much better ways of handling this that don't disable core functionality like calling events.  Create a global boolean variable (name something like ClearingData) and initialize it to "False".  At the start of your function you check if the boolean is set to true and if it is, "Exit Sub", if not, set it to True continue code execution.  At the end of the function, set ClearingData back to False.  Use good error handling to make sure that ClearingData ALWAYS gets set back to false when the function Exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add a bit around Rory's comment - your problem here is that you've created an infinite loop in your code.

From a very high level here is what's happening:

```
1. You change a value on your worksheet
2. The Worksheet_Change() code is called
3. This code then changes something on the same worksheet
4. This change causes the Worksheet_Change() code to run again
5. This code then changes something on the same worksheet
6. This change causes the Worksheet_Change() code to run again
7. This code then changes something on the same worksheet
8. This change causes the Worksheet_Change() code to run again
9.This code then changes something on the same worksheet

   (you get the picture...)
```

To get around this you need to disable any further events from being called in your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False '// stop further events from firing

    Count = Range("A3").Value
    BundleDup = Range("B3").Value
    duplicateall = Range("C3").Value
    SAPError = Range("D3").Value

    If Target.Address = "$A$10" And Count = 6 And BundleDup = 0 And duplicateall = 0 And SAPError = 0 Then

        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
        Application.Wait waitTime
        Call MoveData
    End If

    If Count <> 6 Then
        Call ClearData
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True '// re-enable events

End Sub
```

Finally, if you're going to change application level settings in your code - I would **strongly** recommend you write a proper error handler into your code to revert any such settings in the event of a run-time error.

Comment: As I mentioned above, there are better ways of handling this.  This bit of code is a classic example of a situation where disabling events can be problematic.  If the user simply adds in a "OnWorksheetChanged" event. they would end up with that piece of code not firing.  It's like turning off the power to your whole house, just to change a light bulb safely.  Handle the specific event by handling that event, not by shutting down all events.  Kudos for the mention about good error handling!

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm afraid I have to disagree - the code in this instance is testing for a range address of `$A$10` and calls the other procedure accordingly - the code that is being called then changes the value of `$A$10` creating a closed loop. In the particular instance the only way around this is to disable/enable events manually. Even if another change event needs to be triggered then `DoEvents` will allow this to happen and overall is less overhead with finer control over the runtime logic.

Comment: What you're describing above sounds more like the `IDisposable` implementation from `.NET` which doesn't behave in the same way that VBA does, one of the woes of event driven programming vs object-orientated programming I guess.

Comment: I understand about the recursive loop being created, but disabling events is not the only way to stop it.  A global boolean targets just the specific event that you want to stop and not all events.  Disabling events creates a situation where code outside of the function is disabling the events for reasons completely outside of that code.  Now you're in the mode of trying to backtrack what events were called and handling each of them individually.  Good code should be as self-contained as possible and should not impact anything outside of the function itself.

Comment: Indeed, but VBA is executed on a single thread - and so I don't think your idea of having a global boolean would work. You can't initialise a global variable outside of a procedure, and the executing code isn't going to be called by anywhere else again until it's finished - which means that the boolean will always have the same value by the time the event is called in the stack. I'd love to see an implementation of what you're talking about in VBA, and I'd be genuinely happy to be wrong here - but I just don't believe it's possible in "native" VBA.

Comment: @FrankBall : The code is doing what it suppose to do. Now the only issue is as soon as I type a value in A5 the code clears the data. I want the code to execute when it sees a change in value in cells A5, A6, A7, A8, A9 & A10 and wait. Then decide if the total in A3 is less than 6 clear the cells.

Answer (score 2):

This is how this situation should be handled:

```
    Public ClearingData As Boolean  'initializes natively to "False"

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ClearingData Then Exit Sub 'stops the recursive loop
    ClearingData = True

    Count = Range("A3").Value
    BundleDup = Range("B3").Value
    duplicateall = Range("C3").Value
    SAPError = Range("D3").Value

    If Target.Address = "$A$10" And Count = 6 And BundleDup = 0 And duplicateall = 0 And SAPError = 0 Then

        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
        Application.Wait waitTime
        Call MoveData
    End If

    If Count <> 6 Then
        Call ClearData 'Here's where the recursive loop gets created.
    End If

    ClearingData = False

    End Sub
```

This prevents a recursive loop from starting and still leaves Events enabled. The code handles the specific situation completely within the function, avoiding unexpected results which could effect other functions.

If the "MoveData" function changed cell selection and you had a "Worksheet_SelectionChange" event being called, disabling events would prevent that event from being called.  By using the above logic, the event would still be called. If you wanted to prevent the "Worksheet_SelectionChange" from being called from this function, you simply include the line "If ClearingData Then Exit Sub" at the start of the "Worksheet_SelectionChange" event.

Sorry, I used the term "Global" instead of "Public" in my comments above.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Just to give you the full picture. The data that gets populated from A5 to A10 is from a barcode scanner. I working with the barcode scanner tech support to get scan complete bit once the data is read. Once I get that I can use that bit as trigger to decide when to clear the data. The code that you have written is correct and that's how it should work.